# Why it can work in windows but can't work in Linux?

Tags: c, linux

My code is as follows.

When I use Visual Studio to compile , debug and execute, it's right. And when I use 'gcc' to compile , it's also right, but it's wrong when execute in Linux. The memory is wrong when it run.

And when print 'szBuf', the wrong is can't access the memory.

I want to know why it can work when in Windows but can't work in Linux?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void ItoA(int nNum, char *pStr);
void Print(const char *pFormat, ...);

int main()
{
    char  ch = 'a';
    int nNum = 11;
    char szBuf[255] = "";

    Print("ch: %c\n", ch);
    Print("n: %d\n", nNum);
    Print("s: %s\n", szBuf);

    return 0;
}

void ItoA(int nNum, char *pStr)
{
    if (NULL != pStr)
    {
        char szNum[255] = "";
        int i = 0;

        for (i = 0; 0 != nNum; i++)
        {
            szNum[i] = nNum % 10 + '0';
            nNum /= 10;
        }

        for (i = i - 1; i >= 0; i--, pStr++)
        {
            *pStr = szNum[i];
        }
        *pStr = '\0';
    }
}

void Print(const char *pFormat, ...)
{
    if (NULL != pFormat)
    {
        char *pTemp = (char *)&pFormat;
        pTemp += 4;

        while ('\0' != *pFormat)
        {
            if ('%' == *pFormat)
            {
                pFormat++;
                switch (*pFormat)
                {
                case 'c':
                {
                    putchar(*pTemp);
                    pTemp += 4;
                }
                break;
                case 'd':
                {
                    char szBuf[255] = "";
                    int nNum = 0;

                    ItoA(*(int *)pTemp, szBuf);

                    for (int i = 0; '\0' != szBuf[i]; i++)
                    {
                        putchar(szBuf[i]);
                    }

                    pTemp += 4;
                }
                break;
                case 's':
                {
                    for (int i = 0; '\0' != (*(char **)pTemp)[i]; i++)
                    {
                        putchar((*(char **)pTemp)[i]);
                    }

                    pTemp += 4;
                }
                break;
                default:
                {
                    pFormat--;
                    putchar(*pTemp);
                }
                break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                putchar(*pFormat);
            }
            pFormat++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Incidentally, what gave you the idea this should work? Is it code you copied from somewhere?

Comment: [Cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming)

Comment: I have learned C and C++. I edit , compile and run it in VC++6.0 and VS2017 and it run well. This is my homework, similar homework and string processing function like Scanf , StrLen , StrCmp, StrCat, StrCpy and so on.When I use input and output and string processing in my other jobs, I also write by myself. And I think everyone can't find and copy this code easily in the Internet.

Comment: I can't open the website you give.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While some calling conventions use **the stack** to pass function arguments,
there are some calling conversions that use **registers** to pass ones.

Your code **may** work with calling conventions that use **the stack**, but **won't** work with ones that use **registers**.

It seems that the default of your Visual Studio is x86 compile (32-bit, in which typically the stack is used) and the default of your gcc is 64-bit compile (in which typically registers are used).

You should use APIs in [stdarg.h](https://linux.die.net/man/3/stdarg) to fetch values from variable argument lists.

Comment: It doesn't work even if the stack is used for passing arguments. `pFormat` is a local variable within `Print`, and `&pFormat` need not have anything to do with the storage (on the stack or otherwise) by which the argument was conveyed into the function.

Comment: @R.. Yes, there are no guarantee about what will happen, but it **may happen to seem working well**. [Good result](https://imgur.com/OmRkeJN.png) is produced in my environment.

Comment: Thank you very much , your answer is useful for me， I have solved the problem.And it can also work well when run in my Windows.

Answer (score 1):

These lines and everything surrounding `pTemp` have undefined behavior:

```
    char *pTemp = (char *)&pFormat;
    pTemp += 4;
```

You must use `va_start` and `va_arg` from `stdarg.h` to get at variadic arguments. `&pFormat` is the address of a local variable in the `Print` function, and has nothing to do with how the argument was passed. Arithmetic on a pointer to one object cannot yield a pointer to another object.

Comment: Not to mention the 4-byte/8-byte pointer 32-bit/64-bit conundrum...

Comment: Thank you very much , your answer is useful for me， I have solved the problem.